# Database MYSQL Sum and Avg Automation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name Student as shown in image

[image: please click here to view image as i do not have permission to post image directly till now.]

I want to find total and avg to show in their respective column automatic as i enter the value of marks of subjects and if i want to insert value in total and avg column manually by using query it should show me error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the guide lines for posting and you must show your sql code so people can help faster and give any advice.

Comment: Simply calculate Sum & Average in a View.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: I am using mysql version 5.5.50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of mysql supports generated columns then you could use this feature. Mysql will throw an error if you try to insert to a generated column. For example.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int, s1 int,s2 int, total int as (ifnull(s1,0)+ifnull(s2,0)));

insert into t(id,s1,s2) values (1,10,20);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
insert into t(id,s1,s2,total) values (2,20,null,5);
ERROR 1906 (HY000): The value specified for computed column 'total' in table 't' ignored

select * from t;
+------+------+------+-------+
| id   | s1   | s2   | total |
+------+------+------+-------+
|    1 |   10 |   20 |    30 |
+------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Generally though you should not store items which can be calculated. Also note the ifnull tests. Your question doesn't way whether there will a value for all subjects so you should code for the possibility in totalling and averaging.

Answer (score 1):

based on your data sample  you should add the values for each argument  and divede the result for the numbers of arsgs

```
select  RollNo
        , Name
        , STD
        , Mobile_no
        , physics
        , Chemstry
        , Maths
        , Hindi
        , English
        , ( physics+ Chemstry+ Maths+Hindi+ English) as Total
        ,  ( physics+ Chemstry+ Maths+Hindi+ English) / 5 as  average
from my_table
```